# Remove duplicate elements across multiple lists java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have three lists of strings. Now I need to make sure that an element is present in only one of those three list. I don't want to have duplicates across the lists. You can assume that there are no duplicates within each list.

I tried to use the `removeIf()` and its serving my purpose. Im sure that is not the best way to do it. Is there any other way to do it in Java 8+?

**The Priority for the lists is list1 > list2 > list3**

```java
List<String> list1 = Stream.of("23","45","655","43","199").collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> list2 = Stream.of("13","23","54","655","111","13").collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> list3 = Stream.of("76","45","33","67","43","13").collect(Collectors.toList());

list2.removeIf(i->list1.contains(i));
list3.removeIf(i->list1.contains(i) || list2.contains(i));

System.out.println(list1);
System.out.println(list2);
System.out.println(list3);
```

The output is below which is expected

```
[23, 45, 655, 43, 199]
[13, 54, 111, 13]
[76, 33, 67]
```

Comment: `list2.removeAll(list1);` for the first step would be neat. Also, if you have used `Set` instead of a list, the complexity would have been O(n) for each step. for lists it is O(n^2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will recommend to use `Set` instead of `List` since `Set` is of `O(1)` time complexity

```
 List<String> list1 = Stream.of("23","45","655","43","199").collect(Collectors.toList());
 List<String> list2 = Stream.of("13","23","54","655","111","13").collect(Collectors.toList());
 List<String> list3 = Stream.of("76","45","33","67","43","13").collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And then just stream all there by combining and just collect distinct elements into corresponding lists using `Collectors.groupingBy`

```
Collection<List<String>> result = Stream.of(list1,list2,list3)
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(v->list1.contains(v) ? 0 : (list2.contains(v) ? 1 : 2))).values();

    System.out.println(result);  //[[23, 45, 655, 43, 199], [13, 54, 111], [76, 33, 67]]
```

Comment: Quite complicated, but you did it one line.